# How can I apply a Gabor filter to a sine waveform?

Tags: filters, gabor, filter-bank

I am an ECE student, and I am doing my project on underwater communication.

The main concept of my project is to denoise the signal by using UFB and WPD algorithms, and giving that output to a matched filter. I have already generated the sinewave and added noise and given it to the matched filter.

How do I write the code for UFB (uniform filter bank)?

Comment: You want to apply a gabor filter to 1D sinusoidal waveform?

Comment: What code have you written already?